# CakePHP 3.1 Random error from DebugKit timer

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

I randomly see errors from Debug Kit in CakePHP relating to a template filename string, when it is passed to MessageFormatter. Sometimes the view loads fine, other times it fails with the following:

> Fatal error: [Aura\Intl\Exception\CannotFormat] Invalid UTF-8 data in
>   string argument:
>   '/Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/src/Template/Error/error500.ctp':
>   U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
>
> #0
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php(51):
>   Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->_formatMessage('en_US', 'Render
>   {0}', Array)
>
> #1
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/aura/intl/src/Aura/Intl/Translator.php(142):
>   Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->format('en_US', 'Render {0}', Array)
>
> #2
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php(81):
>   Aura\Intl\Translator->translate('Render {0}', Array)
>
> #3
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Panel/TimerPanel.php(85):
>   __d('debug_kit', 'Render {0}', '/Users/daniel/c...')
>
> #4
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(409):
>   DebugKit\Panel\TimerPanel->DebugKit\Panel{closure}(Object(Cake\Event\Event),
>   '/Users/daniel/c...')
>
> #5 /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/m in
>   /Users/daniel/cakebox/Apps/mycake3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php
>   on line 156

I've tried a number of debugging options, but I can't work out what the issue is? The string looks fine to me, and is confirmed as UTF-8 by mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');